# Marker in leaflet, click event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
var map = L.map('map');
var marker = L.marker([10.496093,-66.881935]).on('click', onClick);
function onClick(e) {alert(e.latlng);}
marker.addTo(map)
```

When I do click in the marker, the alert message is: undefined

But if I put it in the variable map, it works! (shows latitude and longitude)

```
map.on('click', onClick);
```

Does someone know why it doesn't work in the marker?

Comment: Does `var marker = L.marker([10.496093,-66.881935]).on('click', funciton(e) {alert(e.latlng);});` yield the same results?

Comment: I made the change you mentioned but does not work

Comment: Following Chris's post below, you could modify your code as `var marker = L.marker([10.496093,-66.881935]).addTo(map).on('click', onClick);`

Comment: Why must we `addTo(map)` ? That messes up [Leaflet Map Cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) :-(

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
function onClick(e) {
   console.log(this.getLatLng());
}
```

used the method getLatLng() of the marker

Answer (score 116):

The accepted answer is correct. However, I needed a little bit more clarity, so in case someone else does too:

Leaflet allows events to fire on virtually anything you do on its map, in this case a marker.

So you *could* create a marker as suggested by the question above:

```
L.marker([10.496093,-66.881935]).addTo(map).on('mouseover', onClick);
```

Then create the onClick function:

```
function onClick(e) {
    alert(this.getLatLng());
}
```

Now anytime you mouseover that marker it will fire an alert of the current lat/long.

However, you could use 'click', 'dblclick', etc. instead of 'mouseover' and instead of alerting lat/long you can use the body of onClick to do anything else you want:

```
L.marker([10.496093,-66.881935]).addTo(map).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latlng);
});
```

Here is the documentation: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-event

Comment: I think this has changed, now you can do `console.log(e.latlng)` to show an object containing latitude and longitude.

Comment: It would be nice to also include how to prevent that click from propagating.

Answer (score 28):

Here's a jsfiddle with a function call:
https://jsfiddle.net/8282emwn/

```
var marker = new L.Marker([46.947, 7.4448]).on('click', markerOnClick).addTo(map);

function markerOnClick(e)
{
  alert("hi. you clicked the marker at " + e.latlng);
}
```

Comment: how to access the marker's properties like name and other variables?

Comment: @nikhilvj : here's an extended jsfiddle with some additional options: https://jsfiddle.net/8282emwn/139/

Answer (score 21):

Additional relevant info:
A common need is to pass the ID of the object represented by the marker to some ajax call for the purpose of fetching more info from the server.

It seems that when we do:

```
marker.on('click', function(e) {...
```

The `e` points to a MouseEvent, which does not let us get to the marker object. But there is a built-in `this` object which strangely, requires us to use `this.options` to get to the `options` object which let us pass anything we need. In the above case, we can pass some ID in an option, let's say `objid` then within the function above, we can get the value by invoking: `this.options.objid`

Answer (score -4):

A little late to the party, found this while looking for an example of the marker click event. The undefined error the original poster got is because the onClick function is referred to before it's defined. Swap line 2 and 3 and it should work.

Comment: That's incorrect. See hoisting in Javascript https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting