# Creating dynamic links with leaflet onclick event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Im having trouble creating links to a separate dynamic page, where the user is directed to the page when they click a marker created by leaflet. The code below almost entirely works; however, when the marker is clicked instead of going to the relevant page, all the markers link to the last link generated by the loop

---

```
//Add a marker to the map on the results page for each result
function Addmarker(markerArray){

    var dynamicname = 'marker';
    var dynamicnumb = 'numb';
    //create an empty list to hold each marker
    var markerList = [];
    //For each result creater a marker and push it to markerList
    for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
        //Turn the park id into an integer
        var toInt = parseInt(markerArray[i][2]);
        //Generate the marker in the form L.marker(Latitude, Longitude, Name of Park to be shown on mouse over, link to the individual item page on click).add the marker to mymap
        this[dynamicname+i] = L.marker([markerArray[i][0], markerArray[i][1]], {title: markerArray[i][3]}).on('click', function(e) {markerURL(toInt);}).addTo(mymap);
        //Place the marker in a list
        markerList.push(this[dynamicname+i]);
    }
    //Create a feature group of the markers in markerList
    var group = new L.featureGroup(markerList);
    //Auto scale the map to fit all the markers perfectly
    mymap.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(0.2));
}

//create a dynimic link to the individual items page specified in the parameter itemsID
function markerURL(itemsID){
    window.location.href = 'Items.php?parkid=' + itemsID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Closures, closures, closures.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
function Addmarker(markerArray){
    for (i = 0; i < markerArray.length; i++) {
        var toInt = parseInt(markerArray[i][2]);

        this[dynamicname+i] = L.marker(
            [markerArray[i][0], markerArray[i][1]], 
            {title: markerArray[i][3]}
        ).on('click', onMarkerClick(toInt)).addTo(mymap);

}

function onMarkerClick(itemsID){
    return function(ev) {
        window.location.href = 'Items.php?parkid=' + itemsID;
    }
}
```

See also [Leaflet marker event fires at wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time/35429902) , which is pretty much a duplicate of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You must create an associative array and keep the key of each data in the marker object.

```
// generate a unique id
var toInt = parseInt(markerArray[i][2]);

// create marker object, add it to the map
var marker = L.marker([markerArray[i][0], markerArray[i][1]], {
  title: markerArray[i][3]}).on('click', function(e) {
     markerURL(e.target.ID); // url = markerList[e.target.ID][3];
  }).addTo(map);

// keep the unique id in the marker object  
marker.ID = toInt;

// create an item in the associative array
markerList[toInt] = markerArray[i];
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pg8uDbDphMKmtnX2BNG1?p=preview)