# Leaflet.contextmenu callbacks

Tags: javascript, leaflet, contextmenu

I'm struggling with a problem in the `Leaflet.contextmenu` library.

I got a number of different maps, saved in a global Array. Then I'm using the `contextmenu` options to have a `contextmenu` in my maps. When I want to define my callback functions, I can't access my `arrMap[id]`, because the function doesn't know the `id` I'm using.

My question here is: How can I give an object (the `id`, for example) into a callback function of the `Leaflet.contextmenu` library?

```
function x(){
    arrMap[id] = new L.map('map'+id,{
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuWidth: 140,
        contextmenuItems: [{
            text: 'Messung an dieser Position einfügen',
            callback: newMeasurement
        }, {
            text: 'zeige Koordinaten',
            callback: showCoordinates
        }, {
            text: 'Karte hier zentrieren',
            callback: centerMap
        }]
    });
}

function newMeasurement(e){
//do something with e AND ID
}
```

I thought about something like:

```
//function x(){...
callback: newMeasurement(e,id)
//...}

function newMeasurement(e,id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

...but that's not working :(

Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a closure over the value you want.

First, read the [«How do JS closures work?»](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work#111111) question.

Then, read the [MDN reference for closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). And then, [this question about how to create different Leaflet event handlers passing a different value to each handler function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time/35429902#35429902)

---

Read those first. Try to understand the concept. I mean it. If you blindly copy-paste code, then the gods of stackoverflow will kill a kitten.

---

Now, you want to have an event handler function, which will receive just one parameter, like

```
function newMeasurement(ev){
    // do something with 'ev' AND 'id'
}
```

That function *needs* to receive one parameter, and *needs* to have an `id` variable somewhere. OK then, let's create a function that returns a function:

```
function getMeasurementHandler(id) {
    return function(ev) {
        doSomething(ev, id);
    }
}
```

That way, if you run e.g.:

```
var handlerForId1234 = getMeasurementHandler(1234);
```

That is more-or-less equivalent to

```
var handlerForId1234 = function(ev) { doSomething(ev, 1234); }
```

Let's put it all together:

```
for (var id=0; id<4; id++) {
    arrMap[id] = new L.map('map'+id, {
        contextmenuItems: [{
            text: 'Somethingsomething',
            callback: getEventHandlerForId(id)
        }]
    });
}

getCallbackFuncForId(id) {
    return function(ev) {
        console.log('Event ', ev, ' in ID ', id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, havent heard of these closures yet, pretty exited, that you can do things like this! 
thank you sir!