# pass arguments inside button onclick function inside bindPopUp in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create a button listener function inside bindPop in leaflet. But `it does not read parameter of onclick function`. In the below code `alertConfirmed()function works fine` for me `but` `filterEventsBasedOnCluster(feature) does not read the parameter 'feature'`. It says **feature is not defined**. **feature is an object**.

**here is the code:**

```
 layer.bindPopup('<div id="alert">Found...!<input type="button" value="Please confirm" onclick="alertConfirmed()"> <input type="button" id="create" value="see patients" onclick="filterEventsBasedOnCluster(feature)"><table id="table"></table></div>')
```

`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Currently you are sending your parameter feature as a 'feature' object. You should be sending it like +feature+ if you have defined feature as a variable object in your program.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach event handlers via the [`onclick` HTML attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick), you can not control the parameters received by that handler. Let me quote the docs:

> The single argument passed to the specified event handler function is a `MouseEvent` object. Within the handler, `this` will be the element upon which the event was triggered.

The way to pass a custom argument is to define a closure, by having a function that returns a function that receives only the event reference.

This is exactly the same solution as described in «[Leaflet.contextmenu callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657245/leaflet-contextmenu-callbacks/40657869#40657869)» and «[Leaflet marker event fires at wrong time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time/35429902#35429902)».

Read that. I mean it.

---

So in the end it should look something like:

```
function getHandlerForFeature(feat) {  // A function...
    return function(ev) {   // ...that returns a function...
        console.log(feat);  // ...that has a closure over the value.
    }
} 

layer.bindPopup("<button id='mybutton'>Foo!</button>")

// The button doesn't exist in the DOM until the popup has been opened, so
layer.on('popupopen', function(){
    L.DomEvent.on( 
         document.getElementById('mybutton'), 
         'click',
         getHandlerForFeature(layer) // The result of this call is the event handler func.
    );
});
```

Note that you can *not* use the `onclick="code"` syntax, as you need to create a *string* of runnable code, and that code will only be able to access variables in the global scope. Sure, you can `JSON.stringify()` your data, but you won't be able to have references to variables outside.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

I am just correcting the wrong part only:

```
onclick="filterEventsBasedOnCluster('+feature+')"
```

You are not passing the variable properly.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. However it says 'Unexpected identifier'. Its not taking up double quote ending , that is, ('+feature+')"

Comment: Yeah.  I have just shown you the way of handling.hit it is as an answer if I solved your problem