# Passing JSON var in leaflet "on()" method

Tags: javascript, django, dom, onclick, leaflet

I'm working (with Django framwork) on a map with the leaflet library, I want to show some text in a div when I click on a marker.

I've made a JS function to create a div with some text in it:

```
function create_div(text):
{
    div = document.createElement(div);
    div.id = 'article';
    div.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

and then I call this function in the "on" methode given by leaflet
because I want to call it when I click on a marker :

```
var articles = {{ list_json | safe }};
for (var i = 0; i < {{ nb_of_articles | safe }}; i++)
{
    var text = articles[i].fields.text; //I put the text of the i-th marker in text.
    var lat = articles[i].fields.lat;
    var lon = articles[i].fields.lon;
    var marker = L.circleMarker([lat,lon]);

    marker.on('click', function(e) {create_div(text);} );
    marker.addTo(mymap);
}
```

It kinda work but it puts the text of the last object in all the div associate with my marker.

---

For example if I have:

```
article[0].fields.text = "hello"
article[1].fields.text = "world"
```

I get "world" in the divs, regardless of the marker I click on.

---

I would like "hello" in the div when I click on the first marker, and "world" in the div when I click on the second marker.

Here is what it looks like after I click on any of the markers:

[image: after I click]

I hope I'm clear enough, please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Classic JS scope issue. You should be able to find many resources on that topic, including here on SO.

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet marker event fires at wrong time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428801/leaflet-marker-event-fires-at-wrong-time)

Comment: Oh ok !! i'm new to JS and I've just discover this closure shit !! Thank you ! :)  I will edit the post with my solution when I figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go for the saving solution : I use `let` for the declaration of `text`, it will solve the closure issue.

```
let text = articles[i].fields.text;
```

( [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable) )

I hope this is a good solution :)