# how to route to another page in Ionic 4 using Leaflet Marker onclick

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, ionic4, angular-routing

I'm dealing with a problem I've been stuck on for a few days. I'm currently wanting my markers to navigate to another page when clicked on the Leaflet Map. So my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) of the `marker.on('click', someFunction)` leaflet method is that it is performed within the class of the marker even if the function is present in a page.ts file.

I would like some help on calling my router in my page.ts file to navigateByURL to another page when the marker is clicked.

The error I currently get is router Undefined and sometimes navigateByURL undefined.

What I currently have is...

```
displayMarkerLocations(){
  this.places.forEach(place => {
    var marker = L.marker([place.location.Y, place.location.X]);
    marker.on('click', this.OnClick);
    marker.bindPopup(place.address);
    marker.noMoveStart = true;
    marker.addTo(this.markerLayer);
  });
}

onClick(e){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs/tab3');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927793/marker-in-leaflet-click-event check this out

Comment: is it a typo? you have OnClick and onClick?

Comment: Sergey Rudekno, sorry that was a typo when I entered the question, they're both onClick.

Comment: `onClick(e)
      {
        console.log(this);
        var content = e.target.getPopup().getContent();
        console.log(content);
        this.navCtrlData.navigate('/tabs/tab3', {content: content});
      }` works with ` marker.on('click', this.onClick, this); ` using this dependency `import { NgxNavigationWithDataComponent } from 'ngx-navigation-with-data';` . On arrival to new page I get data that was passed using `ionViewDidEnter() {
    console.log(this.navCtrl.get('content'));
    this.parseOutageDetails(this.navCtrl.get('content'));
  }`